# Can I expect when handling pagination in MS Graph, that a 'nextLink' will always be directly before the collection in a json object response?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

After watching the Microsoft video on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging), I decided that I should start testing for server-side pagination by looking for @odata.nextLink fields in all my Graph API (v1.0) query responses, particularly on SharePoint resources.  [In the video at about 1:38s](https://youtu.be/DB_NoC9a1JI?t=98), one of the presenters says that the nextLink is "typically" placed next to the collection in the response.

So far, this is what I have encountered when I analyze the json response of the queries: the collection field is placed immediately after the @odata.nextLink field in the json object.  In the example below, the collection field, 'value' immediately follows the field, '@odata.nextLink'.
[image]

However, I am a little concerned about the presenters choice of words ("typically").  **Can I expect this to always be the case though with Graph API?**

I would like to know if I can build my query algorithm such that whenever I encounter a nextLink, I look to the next field to be the collection that I'll perform concatenation on when visiting the nextLink fields, or if there are cases that will break the algorithm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never assume a fixed order in any serialized response. In the case of OData, a `nextLink` will always be a top-level property but [it can appear above or below](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html#_Toc38457734) the collection being returned:

> All annotations or control information for a structural or navigation property MUST appear as a group immediately before the property itself. The one exception is the `nextlink` of a collection which MAY appear after the collection it annotates.

It's also worth noting that while other annotations always appear before the collection, the spec does not specify the order of those annotations (with some exceptions such as `id` and `etag`).

When working with JSON, properties are best retrieved by name (typically by deserializing the response).

Comment: Based on your response and looking at my example, will the collection associated with a nextLink always be named, 'value'?  When it comes to pagination, 'value' is the only name I've seen for collections so far.

Comment: Yes, it will always return the collection in an array named `value`.

Comment: You may also find the OData spec helpful here, http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html#_Toc38457769